# Getting access token from within identityserver

Tags: identityserver3

I have a scenario where during IUserService.PostAuthenticateAsync I need to return a partial AuthenticateResult redirecting to a controller action.

This controller action has to call an API for which I need to obtain an access token and at this point you should be seeing where this is going.

It almost sounds like identityserver should be a registered client of itself and I would need to make a second /authorize call from the partial login, which sounds really weird.

Is there a better way from within identityserver to get a token for a partial login user to get to an API?

Comment: I'm curious what are you try to achieve with this design/method? in other words, why you want to do all this? can you update your question with more details of what thinking behind this design? so that someone might suggest a different way to achieve what you want to achieve?

Comment: Which authorisation flow are you using?